# Django Query Count group by

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have read this  thread: [Django query: Count and Group BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470260/django-query-count-and-group-by) and read [django queryset doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/)

I found two way to implement SQL `COUNT GROUP BY`.

**(1) `distinct`**

```
note_list = Note.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('tag').values('tag').distinct()
for note in note_list:
    print note
```

worked for me.

**(2) `annotate`**

```
qs = Note.objects.filter(user=user).annotate(Count('tag')) 
for e in qs:
    print e.tag__count
```

*NOT* worked. `count` always `1`.

When I use `distinct` but not `order_by`, it also not work. I had tried other way, also not worked.

django version: 1.8

MySQL version: 5.6.29

**UPDATE:**

```
Note.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('tag').values('tag').annotate(count=Count('tag'))
```

work well for me!

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the field for grouping. In this example, the notes will be grouped by tag:

> Note.objects.filter(user=user).values('tag').annotate(Count('id'))

Comment: `Note.objects.filter(user=user).values('tag').annotate(Count('tag')) ` I have tried before, not work well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you haven't try it, but there is an another way to do this, using .count() method ( e.q. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#count )

```
Note.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('tag').distinct().count()
```

That will return the exact number of note, grouped by tags.

I suggest you to using POSTGRESQL whereas MySQL, that allow you to do something like that, much easier :

```
Note.objects.filter(user=user).distinct('tag').count()
```